# Strange behaviour jQuery Get and mvc 3 partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view _ImageUploader.cshtml

```
 @model Farmer.WebUI.Areas.Images.HelperClasses.UploaderHelper
    @using Farmer.Translations
    @using Farmer.Translations.Views.News

    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/Apps/FileUploader/fileuploader.js"))
    @Styles.Render(Url.Content("~/Apps/FileUploader/fileuploader.css"))

   <div id="file-uploader">
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
        sizeLimit: 20971520,
        action: '@Url.Action("ImagesUpload", "Image", new { area = "Images"  })',
        multiple: true,
        dragText: 'Drop files here to upload',
        uploadButtonText: 'Upload a file',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        failUploadText: 'Upload failed',
        messages: {
            typeError: "{file} has an invalid extension. Valid extension(s): {extensions}.",
            sizeError: "{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
            minSizeError: "{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
            emptyError: "{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
            noFilesError: "No files to upload.",
            onLeave: "The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
        },
        showMessage: function (message) {
            $.confirm({
                'title': 'Message',
                'message': message,
                'buttons': {
                    '@CommonTrl.Ok': {
                            'class': 'blue',
                            'action': function () {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });
        },
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, data) {
            if (data.success == false && data.limitReached) {
                $.confirm({
                    'title': '@CommonTrl.Message',
                    'message': '@ImagesTrl.LimitReached ' + data.numberOfAllowed,
                    'buttons': {
                        '@CommonTrl.Ok': {
                            'class': 'blue',
                            'action': function () {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                addImage(data.idImage, data.imageType, data.showDescriptionOptions);
            }
        },
        params: {
            idSourceTable: '@Model.IdSourceTable',
            imageType: '@Model.ImageType',
            showDescriptionOptions: '@Model.ShowDescriptionOptions'
        }
    });

    function addImage(idImage, imageType, showDescriptionOptions) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetImagePartial", "Image", new { area = "Images" })',
            data:
            {
                __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),
                idImage: idImage,
                showDescriptionOptions: showDescriptionOptions
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Images-' + imageType).append(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

then i have view where I do this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlImageType", Model.ImageTypeOptions, new { id = "ImageType" })
<div id="Uploader">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //set default values
        $('#ImageType').val('@((int)ImageTypes.NewsGallery)');
        $('#ImageType').trigger('change');
    });
 $(function () {
        $('#ImageType').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetImageUploader", "Image", new { area = "Images" })',
                data:
                    {
                        idSourceTable: '@Model.IdGuid',
                        imageType: $('#ImageType').val(),
                        showDescriptionOptions: '@true'
                    },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Uploader').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my server code

```
public ActionResult GetImageUploader(Guid idSourceTable, int imageType, bool showDescriptionOptions)
        {
            return PartialView("Images/_ImageUploader", new UploaderHelper(idSourceTable, imageType, showDescriptionOptions));
        }
```

When everything is loaded the first time everything works fine. The problem is that when I change my dropdown value, the code on server side is called twice and I do not know why. I debugged in firebug and the first time is a normal ajax call ($('#ImageType').change) but the second time when call returns and success ($('#Uploader').html(data);) executes there is another call to server code which I do not find a reason why this happen

Comment: Curious problem - I can't find anything wrong with your code. Is the change event fired twice as well - or are you just getting second call to your controller action? If it is a second call to the controller action, I would try changing the @Html.DropDownList to a custom html/javascript dropdownlist. Maybe the .NET mvc element is messed up for some obscure reason, which you can't find out since you can't debug it?

Comment: no change event is fired only once. Yes server call is fired twice. When debugged it really looks like .html(data) is taking another shot at server side but I do not know how this is even possible.

Comment: i use chrome developer tools, but I guess firebug also has a network tracking ability, use and see if any useful information about the second call appears there(ex. initiator, method, ...)

Comment: Both request are totaly identicall

Comment: since the requests are identical, there must also be a client event that triggers the request(onChange called twice?), and for ajax there's only javascript that allows for it. Therefore the error lies either in the JS(which seems correct though) or the @HTML.DropDownList thingamajig, which you can't check. My own taste would be to write a custom DropDownList, rather than try fiddling around with ajax(Post instead of get?) or DropDownList parameters - but I have no clue what is causing your problem, maybe someone else.

Comment: Created custom <select> and attached the same event. Still the same thing. So the problem is not in dropdownlist. It must be in JS. Not Funny.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about this line

`$('#ImageType').trigger('change');`

since you are calling it in the ready function, so it must be executed every time the page gets loaded.

but to be honest, I'm not 100% sure about that

Comment: it's true it gets triggered when loaded, but since the ajax call triggers a partial view, the javascript executes only once when the parent view is loaded the first time.

Comment: correct, so you may try to avoid this behavior by differentiating page load from the ajax one.